# How to set a profile picture if it exists using Glide, otherwise use a placeholder?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-glide

I have created a blinding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:profileImage")
fun setProfileImage(imageView: ImageView, profileImage: String) {
    Glide.with(imageView.context).load(profileImage)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .into(imageView)
}
```

And it woks fine. However, when I request the users from a public API, there are some cases in which the `profileImage` is null. My goal is to use Glide when the `profileImage` is not null, otherwise use the placeholder that exists in the drawable directory. This what I have tried to my ImageVIew:

```
android:profileImage="@{user.isProfilePictureNotNull() ? user.profileImage : @drawable.placeholder}"
```

Where `isProfilePictureNotNull()` is defined as:

```
fun isProfilePictureNotNull() = profileImage != null
```

But Android Studio is complaning with:

```
'!=', '%', '*', '+', '-', '/', ':', <, <<, <=, '==', '>', '>=', '>>', '>>>' or '[' expected, got ':'.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're attempting to pass something which is not a String (`@drawable.placeholder`) to your binding adapter. If you replace it with a String, you will see that the error resolves.

My advice would be instead of doing the logic outside of the binding adapter, why not do it inside? Something like this:

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:profileImage")
fun setProfileImage(imageView: ImageView, profileImage: String?) {
    if (profileImage != null) {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(profileImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(imageView)
    } else {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder)
    }
}
```

Now, your XML declaration can simply be:

```
android:profileImage="@{user.profileImage}"
```

Additionally, Glide has a `.error()` call you can put onto the builder. I am not certain if it works with null or what triggers it, but you could give it a shot. It would look something like this, then:

```
        @BindingAdapter("android:profileImage")
fun setProfileImage(imageView: ImageView, profileImage: String?) {
    Glide.with(imageView.context).load(profileImage)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .into(imageView)
}
```